# Print a List Outside of the Function Where it was Created

Tags: c#

I have created a class called Dog which I have added to a list. I am wanting to have a print function to output objects in a list I have created. I have it working within the function that the list has been created in, but I want a separate function that will print the list to the console.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //calling working print feature from within the list function
        DogDatabase.dogList();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public class Dog
    {
        //class that is being added to the list
        public string owner;
        public string name;
        public string colour;
        public Dog()
        {
            owner = "unkown";
            name = "unknown";
            colour = "unknown";
        }

        public Dog(string nm, string cl, string ow)
        {
            name = nm;
            colour = cl;
            owner = ow;
        }

        public string talk()
        {
            return "woof woof";
        }

        public string eat(string food)
        {
            return name + "eats" + food;
        }

        public void SetName(string newName)
        {
            name = newName;
        }

        public void SetColour(string newColour)
        {
            colour = newColour;
        }
    }
    public class DogDatabase
    {

        public static void dogList()
        {
            //lists the Dog class from above
            List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
            dogs.Add(new Dog("Baxter", "blue", "me"));
            dogs.Add(new Dog("Fido", "Black", "peter"));
            //the foreach loops for printing the list
            foreach (Dog printDog in dogs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(printDog.name + " " + printDog.colour);
            }
        }
        public void print()
        {                
         //I am wanting to be able to call this function instead and print
         // the list.
        }
```

Comment: You may want to look into variable lifetime and scope. Your `dogs` list doesn't exist outside your `dogList` function, so it isn't possible.

Comment: So...what's your _question_? What have you tried? What did that code do? What do you want it to do instead? And most importantly, what _specifically_ can't you figure out?

Comment: You can define Dog and DogDatabase classes inside the main (program) class of a console application or out of the program class (you did not show it to us in your question). So, If you defined the in the same class that the Main method is there then you can use [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715941/print-a-list-outside-of-the-function-where-it-was-created/48715995#48715995).

Answer (score 0):

You are using static metod in DogDatabase class and having local list variable in the method. You can not access that variable in the print method.

You need to change the DogDatabase class as following.

```
public class DogDatabase
{
    private static List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();
    public static void dogList()
    {
        //lists the Dog class from above
        dogs.Add(new Dog("Baxter", "blue", "me"));
        dogs.Add(new Dog("Fido", "Black", "peter"));  
    }
    public static void print()
    {                
        //the foreach loops for printing the list
        foreach (Dog printDog in dogs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(printDog.name + " " + printDog.colour);
        }
    }
}
```

then you call it from main method as following.

```
DogDatabase.dogList();
DogDatabase.print();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

**You should define the `dogs` list in a larger scope (*out of `dogList` method*).**

For example I defined the dogs in the `Program` class. Now you can fill it in `dogList` method and print it by `print` method.

Codes: **[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N2MMOd)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    private static List<Dog> dogs;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //calling working print feature from within the list function
        DogDatabase.dogList();
        DogDatabase.print();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class DogDatabase
    {
        public static void dogList()
        {
            //lists the Dog class from above
            dogs = new List<Dog>();
            dogs.Add(new Dog("Baxter", "blue", "me"));
            dogs.Add(new Dog("Fido", "Black", "peter"));
        }
        public static void print()
        {                
            //the foreach loops for printing the list
            foreach (Dog printDog in dogs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(printDog.name + " " + printDog.colour);
            }
        }
     }

    public class Dog
    {
        //class that is being added to the list
        public string owner;
        public string name;
        public string colour;
        public Dog()
        {
            owner = "unkown";
            name = "unknown";
            colour = "unknown";
        }

        public Dog(string nm, string cl, string ow)
        {
            name = nm;
            colour = cl;
            owner = ow;
        }

        public string talk()
        {
            return "woof woof";
        }

        public string eat(string food)
        {
            return name + "eats" + food;
        }

        public void SetName(string newName)
        {
            name = newName;
        }

        public void SetColour(string newColour)
        {
            colour = newColour;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What `Main` class? Also, if it's a `DogDatabase`, shouldn't it keep the data itself? Also, this doesn't even compile since `dogs` is declared outside the `DogDatabase` class

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, No **there is not a rule that force us to define the `dogs` inside the `DogDatabase`**. I defined the `dogs` inside the main class (Program class) and it works well. Also I updated my answer and added a link to a **Live demo**. See It. If you give me a negative score. It is wrong.

Comment: Ahh, you cheated now, surrounding `Dog` inside `Program`. It now works, but it's an extremely bad solution

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, No! Every c# programmer with a little experiences know that a C# console program has a main class and my first code was very similar to the current version. I just warp my code with the main class (`public class Program { }`) for you and added a static keyword to print method. Your conditional mind made a mistake and I show it to you without any frauds.